# when I use data from state charts crash

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js, antd

I am using a tabPan of antd react, this is the code rendered:

```
      <TabPane tab={<span className="tabBtn"><Icon type="bar-chart" />Par Mois</span>} key="1">
        <Bar
          data={data_op_month}
          width={100}
          height={2}
          options={{
            maintainAspectRatio: false
          }}
        />
      </TabPane>
      <TabPane tab={<span className="tabBtn"><Icon type="bar-chart" />Par Trimestre</span>} key="2">
        <Bar
          data={data_op_trimestre}
          width={100}
          height={2}
          options={{
            maintainAspectRatio: false
          }}
        />
      </TabPane>

      <TabPane tab={<span className="tabBtn"><Icon type="bar-chart" />Par Année</span>} key="3">
        <Bar
          data={data_op_year}
          width={100}
          height={2}
          options={{
            maintainAspectRatio: false
          }}
        />
      </TabPane>
    </Tabs>
```

The data injected to charts are loaded from the state, I do this inside the render method.

T got the error when switching between the tabs the application crashes !

..

```
var type_vir1 = {
  label: 'VIR inner-THRW',
  backgroundColor: '#00d2d3',
  borderWidth: 0,
  data: null
};
```

..

```
var type_comm1 = {
  label: 'VIR inner-THRW',
  fill: false,
  lineTension: 0.1,
  backgroundColor: '#00d2d3',
  borderColor: '#00d2d3',
  borderCapStyle: 'butt',
  borderDash: [],
  borderDashOffset: 0.0,
  borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
  pointBorderColor: 'gray',
  pointBackgroundColor: '#fff',
  pointBorderWidth: 1,
  pointHoverRadius: 5,
  pointHoverBackgroundColor: 'black',
  pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
  pointRadius: 1,
  pointHitRadius: 10,
  data: null
};

..

var data_op_mois = [];
var data_op_trimestre = [];
var data_op_year = [];

var data_comm;

var d1, d2, d3;

var data_op_mois1 = [20, 58, 11, 30, 14, 55, 20];
var data_op_mois2 = [20, 58, 11, 30, 14, 55, 20];
var data_op_mois3 = [20, 58, 11, 30, 14, 55, 20];

function init_data(state) {

  console.log("debut init data : state =",state);
  data_op_mois1=state.data_op_mois[0];
  data_op_mois2=state.data_op_mois[1];
  data_op_mois3=state.data_op_mois[2];

  d1 = { ...type_vir1, data: data_op_mois1};
  d2 = { ...type_vir2, data: data_op_mois2};
  d3 = { ...type_vir3, data: data_op_mois3};

  data_op_mois = {
    labels: ['Jan', 'Fev', 'Mars', 'Avril', 'Mai', 'Juin', 'Juill', 'Aout', 'Sept', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
    datasets: [
      d1, d2, d3
    ]
  };

  ..

render(){

..

init_data(this.state)

..

}
```

when the application crashes , it show this error:

> TypeError: can't define property "_chartjs": Array is not extensible
>   TypeError: this.chartInstance is undefined TypeError: can't define
>   property "_chartjs": Array is not extensible

Comment: Can you show us the whole code, we can't make any comment to given code.